# About connecting sql server to c# (with ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I Have a problem in connecting my database to c# in connection string section
this is my code but when i run it , i get an error about this :

> "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 84"

My Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@" Server=TheAddress ; Database=MyDataBase.mdf ; integrated security='True' @");
        Cn.Open();
        SqlCommand Cm = new SqlCommand("", Cn);
        Cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(ID_Food, Name_Food , TypeOfService_Food , Price_Food , Type_Food) VALUES (@ID_Food , @Name_Food , @TypeOfService_Food , @Price_Food , @Type_Food)";
        Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Food", textBox1.Text);
        Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name_Food", textBox2.Text);
        Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeOfService_Food", textBox3.Text);
        Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price_Food", textBox4.Text);
        Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type_Food", textBox5.Text);
        Cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Cn.Close();
    }
```

I Cant Even Open My Connection (Error Happen in declaring SqlConnection)
I know its an Amature Question ... but its made me angry (i cant set it correctly)(with visual studio 2012 & sqlserver management studio 2012)

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is right?

Comment: my main question is it: is the connection string is right????(i changed the address here to "TheAddres" and my database path is right)

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHajiRamezanAli: is your problem resolved?

Comment: im on it and im working on second answer .. first does not work

Comment: If the database has been created **on the server**, then you don't need to add a `.mdf` extension to it - use `Server=TheAddress;Database=MyDataBase;Integrated security=SSPI;`

Comment: and second doesnt work . i give one similar error in both of answers :

Comment: The Error :A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a "@" at the end you should remove from the connection string. You also might consider using the using statements when creating the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects so they are properly disposed.

```
        using (var Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=TheAddress;Database=MyDataBase.mdf;integrated security=True"))
        {
            Cn.Open();
            using (var Cm = new SqlCommand("", Cn))
            {
                Cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(ID_Food, Name_Food , TypeOfService_Food , Price_Food , Type_Food) VALUES (@ID_Food , @Name_Food , @TypeOfService_Food , @Price_Food , @Type_Food)";
                Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Food", textBox1.Text);
                Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name_Food", textBox2.Text);
                Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeOfService_Food", textBox3.Text);
                Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price_Food", textBox4.Text);
                Cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type_Food", textBox5.Text);
                Cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you should also remove single quotes enclosed around `True`

Comment: Opps, thanks for the correction. But it actually does seem to work with the single quotes....weird.

Answer (score -1):

you need to provide valid `connection string` .

Try This :

```
SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TheAddress;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

EDIT : from comments : as you are getting runtime excpetion please check wether you are able to communicate with the server or not.

Check this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674122/Another-reason-for-getting-the-error-A-network-rel)

Comment: @Downvoter please don't forget to add comment explaining my problem.Thanks :)

Comment: i checked the link and i understand that is not for local databases(my database is in my pc (its local) and its not on server)

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHajiRamezanAli: can you show the `TheAddress` value imean server path?

Comment: the path of my database file address in my pc??  it is the address :                                  C:\Users\AMIN\Desktop\project data\resturan_HajiRamezanAli.mdf          and if its not the address of server , tell me about that . tnx